# upload an image with a token to a fastAPI route using POST from reactJS

Tags: reactjs, axios, fastapi

i'm trying to upload an image from client (reactJS) side to fastAPI using a post method

this is my client side

```
const [img, setImg] = useState(null)

const onImageUpload = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.files[0])
        setImg(e.target.files[0])
    }


const handleChange = () => {
        if (!img) setErr("please upload an image")
        else {
            
            let formData = new FormData();
            let token = localStorage.getItem("TikToken")

            formData.append(
                "token",
                token
            )
           
            formData.append(
                "pic",
                img,
                img.name
                )
                

            console.log(formData)
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: "http://localhost:8000/profile/pic/",
                data: formData
                
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            })

            
        }
    }
```

and this is my fastAPI function

```
@app.post("/profile/pic/")
async def setpic(token: str, pic:bytes = File(...)):

    print(pic)
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(pic))
    image.show()
    # response = await store_profile_image(form, str(base64.b64encode(form)))
    return "response"
```

i'm gettin error 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

this is the error

```
Edit:1 Uncaught (in promise) 
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 422', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
message: "Request failed with status code 422"
name: "AxiosError"
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
response: {data: {…}, status: 422, statusText: 'Unprocessable Entity', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
[[Prototype]]: Error
```

what am I doing wrong?
and how to fix it?

EDIT:

i checked the error body ( response > data > detail )

i found this

```
detail: Array(1) 0: 
    loc: (2) ['query', 'token'] 
    msg: "field required" 
    type: "value_error.missing"
```

i changed data in axios request to
`data: { "token" : token, "pic": img}`

i got this in the error body

```
detail: Array(2)
0:
    loc: (2) ['query', 'token']
    msg: "field required"
    type: "value_error.missing"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
1:
    loc: (2) ['body', 'pic']
    msg: "field required"
    type: "value_error.missing"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
length: 2
```

Comment: The body of the 422 error will contain the actual error message - i.e. which field is missing or is failing validation.

Comment: i edited the question, i added this detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass additional parameters with images (i.e. a token) use `token:str = Form(...)`

Indeed, in order to pass an image, the body must be encoded in `multipart/form-data` instead of `application/json`. In this case, the path parameters must be of type `File` or `Form`.

This is not a limitation of FastAPI but is part of the HTTP protocol

```py
@app.post("/profile/pic/")
async def setpic(token: str = Form(...), pic:bytes = File(...)):

    print(pic)
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(pic))
    image.show()
    # response = await store_profile_image(form, str(base64.b64encode(form)))
    return "response"
```

And add the header to your axios request

```js
headers: {
   "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
 },
```

Comment: this solved my problem 
Thank you
could you recommend any good documentation that explains more about this ?

Comment: FastAPI documentation about that : https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms-and-files/